# What does the logo of the resistance in "Dragon Ball Super" stand for?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragonball-super

In *Dragon Ball Super* there is a group that is a resistance against the destruction of Earth by Goku black. They have a logo on their uniforms that has the letters K.C.

What do those letters stand for?

[image: Logo can be seen on helmets here]

[image: Logo can be seen on jackets on the characters to the right here.]

Comment: That looks like a G, not a C.

Comment: The screenshot is not mine. I caught a glimpse of it in dragon ball super but did not have a screenshot. This is from Z series which i totally forgot tjey were there as well

Comment: @JakeGould Depending on the viewing angle
In the image I found here
https://dragonballsuper-france.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/SOFCJ-Raws-Dragon-Ball-Super-056-THK-1280x720-x264-AAC.mp4_snapshot_06.30_2016.08.28_08.34.04.jpg
it looks more like a C than a G

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are known as “Earth's Military” and that logo is not a “K.C.” but rather a “K.G.” which stands for “King’s Guards.” [More info here](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Earth's_Military).

Comment: Oh my god. The original was so long ago I totally forgot about this. Thank you